# PHP Concatenating of image link in echo

Tags: php, image, concatenation, echo

I want to echo the image such that the variables $CatSelected will be the folder of the images and $char and $i are part of the img names :
e.g

```
echo "<img src =\"Images/product/".$CatSelected."/".$char$i."s0.jpg"\>";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 echo "<img src =\"Images/product/".$CatSelected."/".$char.$i."s0.jpg\"\>";
                                                          ^          ^
```

1) You forgot to concatenate `$char` and `$i`.

2) You forgot to escape the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo "<img src ='Images/product/'".$CatSelected."/".$char$i."'s0.jpg'\>";
```