# image not displayed in html5 table on cloud9

Tags: php, mysql, html, cloud9-ide

i needed to fetch some names and image of vegetable from my database and since saving image from mysql table and then retrieving it on web page is a bad idea, i have the images saved in the images/vegetable folder within the workspace. i am working on cloud9 and using the following code snippet:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";



            $images_src="/images/vegetable/".$row['name'].".jpg";
           //  echo "<td>" .$images_src ."</td>"; //this displays the image src correctly

           echo "<td> <img src=$images_src ></img> </td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>";
```

however after execution it displays the broken image icon.
where am i going wrong? is achieving image source this way illegal?

Comment: i have tried using '' and "" for images_src in echo "<td> <img src=$images_src ></img> </td>"; but it doesnt help

Comment: You need to provide the full path to the image. For example: http://yoursiteurl.com/images/vegetables/<image name goes here>. Check the page source and click on the image link to see if the images are loading or not.

Comment: its still showing broken image, saving the broken image shows No File and while i am trying to copy the url and pasting in another tab of browser it says 'Cannot GET /bhaskey/eshopper/images/vegetable/potato.jpg' which the complete image url

Comment: ps, when i am trying out with random google image, it is working fine but not with my images saved in the workspace

Answer (score 0):

First of all the img  tag is a singleton tag. You need not add a closing img tag for it.

Another one is you need to give the full url to the image resources like this:

echo " http://localhost/yourwebsite/$images_src>  "; (if in local server )

or echo " http://www.yourwebsite.com/$images_src>  "; (if in live server )

Try it and let me know if you are still having an issue

Comment: i am using this code now : "$images_src= "https://".$IP."/eshopper/images/vegetable/".$row['name'].".jpg";" its still not working. i have also removed the closing tag for img

Comment: $row['name'] is fetched from mysql table and are name of vegetables like potato or tomato. Images are saved in the "image/vegetable" folder with the same name.

Comment: then your url shall be https://sitename.com/images/vegetables/tomato(suppose).jpg right? So do you have an image called (suppose) tomato.jpg ? I just ran the above code with a dummy image and the image worked fine. I am pretty sure the problem is in the image url

Comment: i am workin on cloud9, and my trial project is say market. inside market is the images/vegetable folder having all the images. and i am trying to create the image url by concatenatimng the fixed part of it that is /market/images/vegetable/ and then i am trying to concatenate the variable part by $row['name'] . and this long time of unsuccessful trial is just encouraging me that it is an illegal way to attempt

Comment: however http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17340959/php-concatenating-of-image-link-in-echo is suggesting otherwise, i am failing to achieve what i want